# Jenkins pipeline check URL exists or does not exists

Tags: jenkins, curl

is it possible to check in jenkins whetehr a url exists or not . if exists i want do few action. Maybe curl or other method

```
                    if (sh(script: 'curl --head --silent --fail <url> 2> /dev/null')) {
                        echo 'Hi'
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute shell scripts (in one of your build steps) to check if given URL exists.
Here is the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474805/verify-if-a-url-exists) that I've found, it might help you out.

Comment: what si the 2>ya

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: Can you give more information? Did you try to add new build step called 'Execute shell'?
Or did you try to modify existing build step that executes shell commands?